How to Load Login URL with Parameters in Flutter WebView After Deep Link Click from Inbox
I'm building my first Flutter app to display my WordPress website in a WebView. Everything works well except the login process.
The app lets users log in by submitting only their email on the main page. They receive a login link via email, which looks like this:
https://newtestwebsiteofmine.com/?uid=110&token=cf7baade7c5f173aaae92d32e2631ea6&nonce=f454a89b51
When they click the link, it should open the app via a deep link and log them in. This works perfectly in a browser, but when the app opens via the deep link, the WebView still shows the "check your inbox for the login URL" screen, and doesn't refresh or load the login URL with the parameters.
Question:
How can I listen for the deep link in the Flutter WebView or force the WebView to load the URL with the login parameters so the user gets logged in?
This is what i did so far:

added deeplink support to AndroinManifest.xml
     <!-- Intent filter for handling deep links -->
     <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         <!-- match any URL that starts with https://newtestwebsiteofmine.com/, including ones with query parameters (?uid=...&token=...)  -->
         <data android:scheme="https" android:host="newtestwebsiteofmine.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
     </intent-filter>


main.dart
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
     import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
     import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

     void main() {
       runApp(const newtestwebsiteofmineCOMM());
     }

     class newtestwebsiteofmineCOMM extends StatefulWidget {
       const newtestwebsiteofmineCOMM({super.key});

       @override
       State<newtestwebsiteofmineCOMM> createState() => _newtestwebsiteofmineCOMMState();
     }

     class _newtestwebsiteofmineCOMMState extends State<newtestwebsiteofmineCOMM> {
       late final WebViewController _controller;
       bool _isLoading = true;
       bool _isError = false;

       @override
       void initState() {
         super.initState();
         _controller = WebViewController()
           ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
           ..setNavigationDelegate(
             NavigationDelegate(
               onPageStarted: (String url) {
                 setState(() {
                   _isLoading = true;
                   _isError = false;
                 });
                 _getCookies(); // Fetch cookies when a page starts loading
               },
               onPageFinished: (String url) {
                 setState(() {
                   _isLoading = false;
                 });
               },
               onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
                 setState(() {
                   _isLoading = false;
                   _isError = true;
                 });
               },
             ),
           );
         // Load the initial URL here
         _controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://newtestwebsiteofmine.com/'));
       }

       // Method to get cookies using JavaScript
       void _getCookies() async {
         await _controller.runJavaScriptReturningResult('document.cookie');
       }

       // Reload page and reset error state
       void _reloadPage() {
         _controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://newtestwebsiteofmine.com/'));
         setState(() {
           _isError = false;
         });
       }

       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return MaterialApp.router(
           title: 'My New Site',
           theme: ThemeData(
             useMaterial3: true,
           ),
           routerConfig: _buildRouter(),
         );
       }

       // Custom error screen widget
       Widget _buildErrorScreen() {
         return Container(
           color: Colors.white,
           child: Center(
             child: Column(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
               children: [
                 Icon(Icons.error_outline, size: 64, color: Colors.red),
                 SizedBox(height: 16),
                 Text(
                   'Ooops hata\nOoops error\nOoops Fehler',
                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                 ),
                 SizedBox(height: 8),
                 Text(
                   'İnternetizi kontrol edin\nCheck your internet\nInternet überprüfen',
                   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                 ),
                 SizedBox(height: 24),
                 ElevatedButton(
                   onPressed: () {
                     _reloadPage();  // Correctly calling _reloadPage
                   },
                   child: Text('Yeniden Yükle\nReload Page\nNeu laden'),
                 ),
               ],
             ),
           ),
         );
       }

       // Use a method to build the router
       GoRouter _buildRouter() {
         return GoRouter(
           initialLocation: '/',
           routes: [
             GoRoute(
               path: '/',
               builder: (context, state) => Scaffold(
                 body: Stack(
                   children: [
                     if (_isError)
                       _buildErrorScreen()
                     else
                       Container(
                         color: Color(0xFF212121),
                         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 52),
                         child: WebViewWidget(controller: _controller),
                       ),
                     if (_isLoading && !_isError)
                       Center(
                         child: SizedBox(
                           width: 64,
                           height: 64,
                           child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                             strokeWidth: 5,
                             valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Color(0xFFdf0000)),
                           ),
                         ),
                       ),
                   ],
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             GoRoute(
               path: '/details',
               builder: (context, state) => Scaffold(
                 appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Details Screen')),
                 body: Center(child: Text('Details Page')),
               ),
             ),
           ],
         );
       }
     }



